Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values in .Net core API
I need to get all the columns from my CourseDto class, here is my code:
public async Task<IEnumerable<TrendingCourseDto>> GetTrendingCoursesAsync()
{

   var trendingCourses = await _categoryDbContext.Courses
       .Include(c => c.Instructor)
       .Include(c => c.Reviews)
       .Where(c => c.Status == "Active")
       .OrderByDescending(c => c.Popularity)
       .Take(6)
       .ToListAsync();

   var trendingCourseDtos = trendingCourses.Select(c => new TrendingCourseDto
   {
       InstructorName = c.Instructor?.FirstName + " " + c.Instructor?.LastName,
       CourseTitle = c.Title,
       Popularity = c.Popularity,
       CourseDescription = c.Description,
       ImageURL = c.ImageURL,
       NumberOfLessons = CalculateNumberOfLessons(c),
       Fee = c.Price.HasValue ? c.Price.ToString() : "Free",
       AverageRating = CalculateAverageRating(c.Reviews)
   });

   return trendingCourseDtos;
}

private int CalculateNumberOfLessons(Course course)
{
   if (course.Sections == null)
   {
       return 0;
   }
   else
   {
       return course.Sections.Sum(s => s.Lessons?.Count ?? 0);
   }
}

private double CalculateAverageRating(ICollection<Review> reviews)
{
   if (reviews != null && reviews.Any())
   {
       return reviews.Average(r => r.Rating);
   }
   return 0;
}

Here is related model and DTo classes:
public class Course:AuditableEntity
 {
     [Key]
     public int CourseID { get; set; }
     public int InstructorID { get; set; }
     public int CategoryID { get; set; }
     public string? Title { get; set; }
     public string? Description { get; set; }
     public decimal? Price { get; set; }
     public string? Level { get; set; }
     public string? Language { get; set; }
     public int Duration { get; set; }
     public string? Prerequisites { get; set; }
     public string? Status { get; set; }
     public string? ImageURL { get; set; }
     public int Popularity { get; set; }

     public virtual Instructor ?Instructor { get; set; }
     public virtual Category ?Category { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Section>? Sections { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Quiz>? Quizzes { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Assignment>? Assignments { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Review>? Reviews { get; set; }
 }

 public class Category: AuditableEntity
 {
     [Key]
     public int CategoryID { get; set; }
     public string? CategoryName { get; set; } 
     public string? CategoryDescription { get; set; }
     public string? CssIconClass { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Course>? Courses { get; set; }

 }
 public class Lesson:AuditableEntity
 {
     [Key]
     public int LessonID { get; set; }
     public int SectionID { get; set; }
     public string? Title { get; set; }
     public string? Content { get; set; }
     public int Duration { get; set; }
     public int OrderIndex { get; set; }
     public virtual Section? Section { get; set; }
 }
 public class Instructor:AuditableEntity
 {
     [Key]
     public int InstructorID { get; set; }
     public int UserID { get; set; }
     public string ?FirstName { get; set; }
     public string ?LastName { get; set; }
     public string? Bio { get; set; }
     public string? ProfilePicture { get; set; }
     public string? Website { get; set; }
     public string? SocialMediaLinks { get; set; }

     public virtual User? User { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Course>? Courses { get; set; }
 }
public class Review:AuditableEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int ReviewID { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public string ?Comment { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReviewDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Course? Course { get; set; }
    public virtual Student? Student { get; set; }
}
 public class Section:AuditableEntity
 {
     [Key]
     public int SectionID { get; set; }
     public int CourseID { get; set; }
     public string ?Title { get; set; }
     public string ?Description { get; set; }
     public int OrderIndex { get; set; }
     public virtual Course ?Course { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Lesson> ?Lessons { get; set; }
 }


public class TrendingCourseDto
{
    public string? InstructorName { get; set; }
    public string? CourseTitle { get; set; }
    public int Popularity { get; set; }

    public string? CourseDescription { get; set; }
    public string? ImageURL { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfLessons { get; set; }
    public string? Fee { get; set; }
    public double AverageRating { get; set; }
}

however when I put the debugger my code fails at this part:
 var trendingCourses = await _categoryDbContext.Courses
       .Include(c => c.Instructor)
       .Include(c => c.Reviews)
       .Where(c => c.Status == "Active")
       .OrderByDescending(c => c.Popularity)
       .Take(6)
       .ToListAsync();

I get this error:
     System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
     at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.ThrowIfNull()
     at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
     at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i)
     at lambda_method39(Closure, QueryContext, DbDataReader, ResultContext, SingleQueryResultCoordinator)
   at 
 
 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at lambda_method6(Closure, Object)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)


Does your database structure and entities match? You may encounter such errors when trying to access nullable properties that mismatched.

I added model classes, can you check?

public virtual Instructor ?Instructor { get; set; } - pretty sure it matters, where exactly that ? is ...

Does this answer your question? Entity Framework Core: `SqlNullValueException: Data is Null.` How to troubleshoot?

@MJX: The key points in the stack trace are GetInt32(Int32 i) and get_Int32() and ThrowIfNull().  One of the int properties on the model is receiving a null value from the database, and an int can't be null.  It may take some trial and error you for you find out which, but the point is that there's a mismatch between the SQL schema and the code where the former allows a null value for a column where the latter does not.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I tried warnings it didn't work and also disable in the project property the same thing

Detect which property cause this error. Use binary search for that. At first comment Include by Include to detect which Entity cause this error, then try to project "not-nullable" properties one by one.

@Fildor thanks there was a null value in the records. but why it was not showing the error, I manually updated all the columns. now getting the data.

Hi Thank you all for your suggestions and answers, I was able to find the null record, I walked through every column and updated in database. I don't know why I was not getting the error in my vs. anyway thank you all

I don't know why I was not getting the error in my vs - you were; that's what the exception is. You wont see it in the errors window in VS because that window is for compiler errors, this is an error that happens after the compiler has finished churning out a program i.e. it happens during runtime. Now that you have fixed your data, go and set all the DB columns of ints to "allow null? = false" so it can't happen again
